# Como ser menos repetitivo em meus códigos JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, estilo-de-codificação

Este meu código parece grande e desajeitado, existe maneira de deixá-lo menor? Algo como "mais fácil de escrever", ou menor?

Eis o meu exemplo, como se pode ver, **preciso repetir este bloco 5 vezes**, para exibir apenas um botão por vez e sua `<div>`, Um para cada botão que eu pressiono.

Estou certo? seria assim mesmo?

```
function analysisShowPage1(){
    $('#page01').removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-success');
    $('#page02').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');
    $('#page03').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');
    $('#page04').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');
    $('#page05').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');
    document.getElementById('analysisFullGraphContainer').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('analysisFullGraphContainer2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('analysisFullGraphContainer3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('analysisFullGraphContainer4').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('analysisFullGraphContainer5').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('copyGraph01').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('copyGraph02').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('copyGraph03').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('copyGraph04').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('copyGraph05').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Tente criar uma função que faça o bloco de comando, economizará muitas linhas de código

Comment: Fiquei curioso com o nome dessa função...`analysisShowPage1`. Existe também o `analysisShowPage2` e `analysisShowPage3`? Isso também é repetição...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nem sempre código repetitivo é ruim. Pode reduzi-lo, mas pode ficar mais difícil de entender. O segredo para eliminar repetições é achar um padrão e mudar o que varia. Tem várias formas de alcançar o objetivo.

Como não foi feito um exemplo mínimo, compilável e verificável, farei um código que provavelmente funciona, mas não tenho como testar:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) { 
    $('#page0' + i).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass(i == 1 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-warning');
    document.getElementById('analysisFullGraphContainer' + i).style.display = i == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('copyGraph0' + i).style.display = i == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Loop.js).

Comment: Obrigado pelo **exemplo de código**! isso sim, ajuda agente que esta comecando, a aprender!  Vou brincar ja!  VALEU!  E, se tiver mais exemplos eu agradeco!

Comment: Como aqui é um site de perguntas e respostas objetivas, você tem que fazer perguntas bem especificas para que seja formulada uma resposta específica. Pode fazer quantas perguntas quiser, sempre providenciando o máximo de informação possível para obter a melhor resposta que dê para fornecer.

Comment: OK! acho que estou entendendo!  obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode iterar tudo dentro de um `for`

Dese modo:

```
function analysisShowPage1() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#page' + i).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-success');
    document.getElementById('analysisFullGraphContainer' + i).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('copyGraph' + i).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Recomendo apenas retirar o 0 do nome das variáveis, o tipo numérico, assume 01 como 1 por exemplo.